# Proving graph has a Hamiltonian path

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph of order $n \geq 2$ such that each vertex has degree $\geq\frac{n − 1}{2}$. Prove that $G$ has a Hamiltonian path.

I noticed that for even $n$,    $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is not an integer therefore each vertex has a degree of at least $\frac{n}{2}$ so $G$ is Hamiltonian by Dirac's theorem.

however, when n is odd we can't use Dirac's theorem anymore so I'm clueless.

Comment: Hint: you only need a Hamiltonian path, not a Hamiltonian cycle

Comment: [Saulspatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3681711) gives a very relevant hint for a slightly stronger question.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks! now i get it